# Can the use of pointers cause memory clogging?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, memory-bandwidth

Suppose I have this structures in `c++`:

```
class A{
  public:
    B b;
}

class B{
  public:
    C c;
}

class C{
  public:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    double s;
    function Usize(){
      s  = sqrt(pow(x,2) + pow(y,2) + pow(z,2));
    }
}
```

Will accessing the the values in `c` ten times require more memory traffic than creating a direct pointer to c and use it? In code terms (assuming legal values):

```
double dx = 2*rand()-1;
double dy = 2*rand()-1;
double dz = 2*rand()-1;

a->b->c.x *= dx;
a->b->c.y *= dy;
a->b->c.z *= dz;

if (a->b->c.x > 10) a->b->c.x -= 10;
else if (a->b->c.x <0) a->b->c.x += 10;
if (a->b->c.y > 10) a->b->c.y -= 10;
else if (a->b->c.y < 0) a->b->c.y += 10;
if (a->b->c.z > 10) a->b->c.z -= 10;
else if (a->b->c.z < 0) a->b->c.z += 10;

a->b->c->Usize();
```

vs.

```
double dx = 2*rand()-1;
double dy = 2*rand()-1;
double dz = 2*rand()-1;


C* ac = a->b->c
ac.x *= dx;
ac.y *= dy;
ac.z *= dz;

if (ac.x > 10) ac.x -= 10;
else if (ac.x < 0)  ac.x += 10;
if (ac.y > 10) ac.y -= 10;
else if (Ac.y < 0) ac.y += 10;
if (ac.z > 10) ac.z -= 10;
else if (ac.z < 0) ac.z += 10;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is wrong, which makes it difficult to know what you are asking. Should the class member declarations be `B* b`and `C* c`, or should the accesses be `a.b.c.x` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this exact case, a good compiler should be able eliminate the common expression and generate pretty much optimal code. Since you're accessing primitive types, a->b->c can be evaluated once and used throughout the method.

The call to C::USize() or access of a non primitive type in "class C" will break this pattern and force the compiler to re-evaluate a->b->c for the next line.

```
a->b->c.x = 10;
a->b->c.Usize();   // <-- Usize() may change a.b so the next line references another B.
a->b->c.y = 5;
```

This is because the compiler cannot make 100% sure that a method call/operator does not change a, a.b or b.c, so it has to re-evaluate the chain to make sure.

I'd almost call worrying about this at this stage premature optimization. That said, your second example is both more readable and helps the compiler not have to second guess in case you insert any method calls later, so I'd go for that.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't follow you. How can a method call prevent the optimization? It doesn't matter if `A` contains `B` contains `C`, the method will still do the same thing.

Comment: I still don't understand. How could `class C` know that it is contained by `class B`? And if it did, how would `C::Usize()` know what instance of `B` to modify?

Comment: If the Usize() implementation is in the same compilation unit, the compiler may figure out that it does not change a, b or c. Consider though that we don't know where a is allocated, there may be a stored pointer to it in another compilation unit that Usize() or anything it calls could use to get to a. The big problem with C/C++ is that the compiler can't assume you're writing clean code, it has to assume the worst.

Comment: But doesn't that hold true whether you call like this `a->b->c->Usize()` or like this `C* pc = a->b->c; pc->Usize()`?

Comment: The difference is that once you set pc, the compiler does not have to consider changes to a or b, pc should not change even if they do. That means the compiler does not have to re-evaluate a->b->c.y to make sure, just evaluate pc.y.

Comment: +1 I get it. I was under the impression that you were saying that `a->b->c` and `pc = a->b->c` could be different at the time `Usize` is called. You were saying that they might be different after it finishes executing.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson So every time I execute an internal function of class a->b->c the compiler re-evaluate whatever points on a->b->c?

Comment: @Yotam Not necessarily. Often times, a compiler can prove that if the method doesn't change the relevant fields, then it doesn't need to be re-evaluated. These are call [Interprocedural Optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization).

Comment: @Mysticial "Often times, a compiler can prove that if the method doesn't change the relevant fields" -- Like in cases where all the objects involved are local and `C` doesn't hold a pointer to either some `A` or some `B` (directly or indirectly)?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Is there a way for me to test this (apart from running the later version on the cluster)? Can valgrind detect this for example?

Comment: @PaulManta Yes, that would be one case. For a simple case like this, what could likely happen is that `Usize()` will get inlined. Then a dependency analysis will reveal that `Usize()` doesn't change `x`, `y`, or `z` - thereby making it possible proceed with the CSE optimization. @Yotam, the only reliable way to test this is to look at the assembly. Writing a micro-benchmark for this might be very tricky due to gazzilion other factors - especially since you're dealing with memory access and cache.

Answer (score 11):

**Chances are no. There will be no difference.**

While it is true that dereference chaining will lead to more memory accesses, modern compilers are able to do exactly what you have done. (That is, transform your first example into your second example.)

This is due to a standard compiler optimization called [Common Subexpression Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) (CSE).

The name pretty much says it all. In your first example, `a->b->c` is the common subexpression that will be optimized out by the compiler. It will be evaluated only once, the result saved, and reused for all the instances it is needed.

---

There are a number of situations that could prevent a compiler from making such optimizations.

1. If any relevant variables are declared `volatile`, then this optimization is not allowed since a `volatile` variable requires that it be reloaded each time it is used.
2. If any of the relevant variables are (or potentially) modified, then this optimization is not allowed since it may produce a different result.

---

As a side-note though, your second example is also more readable since there's dereference chaining.
So if I had to pick which to use, I'd go with the second example anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically **it will not make a difference**.

Any modern optimizer should translate to exactly the same code.

Comment: The more correct way of putting it is that _theoretically_ it should make a difference, but there's no difference _in practice_ because of modern compilers.

Comment: @PaulManta well, what I meant is that *theoretically* all optimizers should be able generate the same code :).